# Biblatex, APA style, hyperlink \parencite not displaying author on 2nd cite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, apa-style

I'm having trouble with my code.
I'd like the 2nd `\parencite` to also include the authors name.

The `\DeclareCiteCommand` is causing the authors name to be absent after the first cite

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Sutherland and Varnam},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    First cite \parencite{A01}.

    Second cite \parencite{A01}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` defines `\parencite` slightly different than the redefinition in your example assumes. That definition works for some of the standard styles, but not for more complicated styles like `authoryear-icomp` and `apa`.

For `apa` you need

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefnonest}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperrefnonest]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperrefnonest]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}


\begin{document}
  First cite \parencite{sigfridsson}.

  Second cite \parencite{sigfridsson}.

\citereset

  First cite \textcite{sigfridsson}.

  Second cite \textcite{sigfridsson}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows both citations with links and identical text "Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998"]

*edit*: Added a redefinition for `\textcite` as well. Note that the parentheses in `\textcite` may not be linked as expected. Fixing that would be much more complicated.

Comment: I had the same issue and your answer solved it for me, Moewe. Do you know of a similar workaround for the \textcite command by any chance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MichielSchreurs See the edit for the analogue redefinition of `\textcite`. Note that that might not give exactly what you want w.r.t. the parentheses. Getting the links right there is much more complicated. If you want that you can ask a new question.

Comment: Revisiting this issue. The redefined `\parencite` worked as I had wished. Now for the `\textcite`. As you mentioned @moewe, the right parentheses is not hyperlinked. How much more complicated would it be to solve this issue?

Comment: @Socadillo I can't say from the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure it would more more complicated. Certainly so complicated that I would want to urge you to ask a new question, since I will not answer it in the comments here.

Comment: In the case of `\parencite`, this implementation also hyperlinks the comma between the author's name and the year, which isn't standard. Is there a way to exclude it?

Comment: @Jana Quite probably yes, but please ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if still needed, but I tried with the following and it seem to inlcude the right parenthesis too:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
{}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
```

Hope it helps, and apologies for not posting a MWE.