# Latexdiff and biblatex citation commands

Tags: biblatex, natbib, latexdiff

I'm having trouble getting `latexdiff` to work when using the `biblatex` citation commands `\parencite` and `\textcite`.

Take `old.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{greenwade93} is the best article on \LaTeX \parencite{goossens93}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and `new.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{goossens93} is the best book on \LaTeX \parencite{greenwade93}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Running `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL old.tex   Sun Jul 26 18:28:46 2020
%DIF ADD new.tex   Sun Jul 26 18:28:55 2020
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

\textcite{\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{greenwade93}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{goossens93}\DIFaddend } is the best \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{article }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{book }\DIFaddend on \LaTeX \DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \parencite{goossens93}%%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \parencite{greenwade93}\DIFaddend .

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which, when compiled with `pdflatex` yields:

[image]

The problem is that `latexdiff` puts the markup commands within the `\textcite` command, which obvious doesn't work. Adding `natbib=true` to the `biblatex` options and changing `\textcite` to `\citet` and `\parencite` to `\citep` gives the correct output:
[image]

The [documentation](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf) (section 4) says:

> The following packages trigger special behaviour:
> ...
> apacite, biblatex
> Redefine the commands recognised as citation commands.

Is this a bug in `latexdiff` or am I missing something?

I'd be happy to use the `natbib` commands instead, but I am using the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537471/156662) to to include the author name in the hyperlink.

EDIT: turns out that the code from moewe to include the author(s) in the citation links works perfectly fine when using the `natbib` command instead of the standard `biblatex` ones. I have no idea how that works, but it solves my immediate problem.

Comment: Either `latexdiff` does not detect `biblatex` correctly or it detects it correctly, but does not handle its commands correctly. In either case I'd say this is a bug or limitation of `biblatex`. I suggest you contact the author about this.

Comment: @moewe I guess you meant to write it is a bug in `latexdiff`. Indeed it is; or better was - I just fixed it on the github repository.  So the answer is either use the master from github repository of latexdiff  or wait for the next release.

Comment: @frederik Oh yeah, absolutely. Muscle memory: I type `biblatex` way too often. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the option `--exclude-textcmd=textcite` to force latexdiff to treat the `\textcite` command correctly (from latexdiff v1.3.2 this behaviour will be the default if biblatex package is used)

Comment: After making my post I tried this but with `textcite` in quotes. Is that not the correct syntax? Because that didn't work.

Comment: I would have expected to have worked with the quotes also. I just tried this, and the result seems to be the same. Maybe there is some dependence on the operating system or shell