# Full citation call-outs to be marked in blue as hyperlinks

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing

I am using overleaf to write my thesis. Currently, citation call-outs are appearing only with the year of publication hyperlinked and blue. I wanted to have the full citation in blue for example -- **Smith et al. 2022** should entirely be hyperlinked and blue; however, currently only **2022** has those properties.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 


\begin{document}

I think that the whole citation of \cite{smith2022overleaf} should be in blue and hyperlinked, not just 2022.


\printbibliography
\appendix
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864.