# Im using Clean Thesis and cant get a good APA style citation with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle, cleanthesis

I am using Clean thesis template for my thesis and I see it uses biblatex. From some searching I found that I can use APA or authoryear to get the format I want but there are two issues with this. If I use one of these only the year is clickable to link to the reference, and secondly it doesn't put it between parentheses. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536353/biblatex-colors-and-links-only-the-year-not-the-rest-of-the-citation) or possibly [Biblatex, APA style, hyperlink \parencite not displaying author on 2nd cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457411/biblatex-apa-style-hyperlink-parencite-not-displaying-author-on-2nd-cite)

Comment: For the correct parentheses you should use the commands `\parencite` and `\textcite` (depending on which bracketing you need - parenthetical or narrative citations).